# How to suppress warning about SLF4J logger not found?

Tags: slf4j

I'm using Ktor Kotlin Framework and it somewhere (probably in Jetty) has `slf4j` dependency. So when I run it I see warning

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Is there a way to hide that? I don't want to see SLF4J or Ktor/Jetty logs as I will have my own custom logging at the Application level.

Ideally - just **hide it without adding SLF4J dependency**.

Comment: You don't want to *hide* it, you want to *fix* it, by providing an implementation JAR.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I did by providing `slf4j-nop` and hiding it :)

Answer (score 3):

This will suppress SL4J logging

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which is cleary stated at the webpage, URL to which is included in the warning: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might have changed with `slf4j` (as of March 2023), but the solutions provided aren't working for me.  I get the following *warning* when I run `mvn test`, even with an `slfj` logging  implementation in my classpath/dependencies:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

This is extra strange because, previously adding an `slfj` logging  implementation **did** make the warning go away.

So, as of now, at least for me, I can't get this warning to go away.

---

After years of mystery, I finally found a solution.

First, my project didn't depend on SLF4J. It was a transitive dependency, that brought with it the annoying warning.

I had a hunch that the SLF4J being added to my project was old and didn't recognize newer SLF4J logger implementations.  So, I added the latest org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7 dependency explicitly.  **That solved the problem.**  My conclusion is that, a newer SLF4J API *will* recognize SLF4J loggers and not print the warning.

Comment: I have noticed that 2.x versions is having no effect now, but 1.7.36 is fixing it and messages are gone